# How can I add a line to Android Dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is an example:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
```

where do I add this?

Comment: in app/build.gradle in dependencies blog. Please remove this question is to easy

Comment: @KonradKrakowiak easy is relative, don't be condescending

Comment: It can be easy but I have an assignment in Android. And I never touched it before. So, don't be like that.

Comment: I mean that you can find it answer in google very quick

Comment: I am sorry I won't to be condescending. I just mark that you should check it in google first

Answer (score 1):

add this line in your app gradle(build.gradle(Module:app)) under dependencies.

```
dependencies 
{
 compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

  Compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'

}
```